# Function to count the number of elements in an OBJECT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a function for counting the number of elements in an `OBJECT` data type? `ARRAY` has `ARRAY_SIZE()`. `VARCHAR` has `LEN()` or `LENGTH()`.

I am used to other query languages where I can use a function like `SIZE()` or `CARDINALITY()`.

Comment: I would have suggested `ARRAY_SIZE(OBJECT_KEYS(x))` for a SQL method, you can always drop into a Javascript function and use some native, "object, tell me the count of root keys you have", if there is one (non-Javascript expert), but I would have counted the root keys there also. So they seems the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can think of using Snowflake SQL to do `ARRAY_SIZE(OBJECT_KEYS(x))`. However, this seems more complicated than it needs to be.

For the special case of checking for empty `OBJECT` (cardinality 0), I could compare `x = OBJECT_CONSTRUCT()`.